# If $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a^2+b^2=c^2$ show that $abc \equiv 0 \pmod{60}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

> If $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a^2+b^2=c^2$ show that $abc \equiv 0 \pmod{60}$.

I once read, on a number theory textbook - forget the title, in one of the problems list that all Pythagorean triplets when multiplied are divisible by 60

Comment: Do you know how the primitive triples can be generated ? If you show that at least one of the numbers must be divisible by $3$ at least one by $4$ and at least one by $5$ , you are done since every triple is a multiple of a primitive triple.

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb{Z}/4$ the square are $0$ and $1$, we cannot have $a=b=1$ mod $4$, in this case $c^2=2$ mod $4$ contradiction.

In $\mathbb{Z}/3$ the square are $0$ and $1$, we cannot have $a=b=1$ mod $3$, since in this case $c^2=2$ mod $3$.

In $\mathbb{Z}/5$ the square are $0,1,4$, we cannot have $a=b=1$ mod $5$ and $a=b=4$ mod $5$, since in this case $c^2=2$ mod $5$, we deduce that $a=1, b=4$ mod $5$, $b=1, a=4$ mod $5$, this implies that $c^2=0$ mod $5$ and $c=0$ mod $5$,

This implies $3,4$ and $5$ are divsors of $abc$ which implies that $abc$ is divisible by $60$.

$a=0$ mod $5$ or $b=0$ mod $5$.

Answer (score 0):

According to the prime factorization $60=2^2\cdot 3\cdot 5$ so it suffices to show $abc\equiv 0\pmod 4$, $\pmod 3$, and $\pmod 5$.

$abc\equiv 0\pmod 4$:  If two or all three of the numbers are even, we are done. Hence assume at least two are odd. As the sum of odd numbers is even, this means that *exactly* two of $a,b,c$ are odd. Thess cannot be $a$ and $b$ as that would make $c^2\equiv 1+1\pmod 8$, which is absurd. Hence $c$ and wlog $a$ are odd. Then $b^2=c^2-a^2\equiv 0\pmod 8$, which means $4\mid b$ and we are done.

$abc\equiv 0\pmod 3$: If any of $a,b,c$ is a multiple of $3$, we are done. So assume otherwise. But then $a^2\equiv b^2\equiv c^2\equiv 1\pmod 3$, whereas $1+1\not\equiv 1\pmod 3$.

$abc\equiv 0\pmod 5$: If any of $a,b,c$ is a multiple of $5$, we are done. So assume otherwise. But then each of $a^2,b^2,c^2$ is $\equiv \pm1\pmod 5$, so $a^2+b^2\equiv$ one of $-2,0,2$, but $\not\equiv \pm1$.